# Перезапись в массив... как сохранить то, что я уже записал

Tags: javascript, массивы

Добрый день. У меня есть пустой массив. Я с помощью функции add_arr добавляю в него значение. В функцию добавил alert, который показывает, что значение было добавлено в массив. А потом как я понимаю (ибо JS я изучаю недавно) происходит перезагрузка страницы и все значения стираются. И когда я нажимаю на кнопку показать массив и она запускает функцию show_arr, то в ней пустой массив. А я, как вы уже поняли, хочу добавлять в массив много значений, а потом нажать на кнопку Показать и я увижу весь массив.... Подскажите, что я не понимаю и какие варианты решения есть.

```
<script>
var a = [];

function add_arr () {
    var good = document.getElementById("good").value;
    a.push(good);
    alert(a);
}

function show_arr () {
    alert(a);
}

</script>

<form id="rrr" onsubmit="show_arr()">
   <input type="submit" value="Показать массив">
</form>

<form id="rrr" onsubmit="add_arr()">
  Введите значение <input id="good" type="text" value="" placeholder="Товар" ><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: @Grundy как ты посмел!!!

Answer (score 0):

в  `onsubmit` добавь `return`, например `onsubmit="return show_arr();"`, а в функциях в конце допиши `return false;`

в ином же случае у тебя просто по дефолту срабатывает поведение формы - отправка

---

еще непонятно конечно зачем тут вообще формы

---

а еще inline уже мало кто пишет. обычно пишут отдельно функции и вешаются слушатели (в данном случае `click`) при которых будут происходить некие события (например работа функции)